# Ask for password while mounting cifs share

Tags: centos, command-line, mount, cifs

I am looking for a way to make the mount command prompt for the password so my password doesn't show up in any system history, I thought I would have it run `read -s -p` command inside of the mount command but I am not having any luck with it. I am wondering if my statement is wrong and how.

```
mount -t cifs -o domain=domain.ad,user=thebtm,pass=$(read -s -p "password: ") "//NAS/thebtm$/" /mnt/cifsmount
password: mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick look at the manual page shows:

```
   password=arg
       specifies the CIFS password. If this option is not given then the
       environment variable PASSWD is used. If the password is not
       specified directly or indirectly via an argument to mount,
       mount.cifs will prompt for a password, unless the guest option is
       specified.
```

So, leave it unspecified, or set the PASSWD env var.

Comment: on Ubuntu it doesn't prompt me. Complained that it can't mount read-only. This approach is for prompting for a username but it worked for me for prompting for the password. It's visible in the terminal though.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067438/allow-user-to-enter-username-before-mounting-shared-drive

Answer (score 5):

To force Centos to prompt you for a password install the following packages:

```
samba-client
cifs-utils
```

You can install these by running `yum install samba-client cifs-utils` as root or with `sudo`.

Comment: The OP must already have these packages because otherwise the `mount` command wouldn't be working at all.

Comment: Those are already installed.

Comment: This is actually a valid solution for the problem as described in the title.  Under Ubuntu, `mounts.cifs` is installed but it fails to mount shares with weird errors (e.g. mount is read only, username not specified, etc.) and it won't prompt for the password when it should.  Installing `cifs-utils` somehow fixes the problem.

Comment: I had exactly that problem and installing these packages exactly fixed it. It was just not asking for a password and printed an error into the messages. Thumbs Up!